# Calculate gradient only in a masked area

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a very large array with only a few small areas of interest. I need to calculate the gradient of this array, but for performance reasons I need this calculation to be restricted to these areas of interest.

I can't do something like this:

```
phi_grad0[mask] = np.gradient(phi[mask], axis=0)
```

Because of how fancy indexing works, `phi[mask]` just becomes a 1D array of the masked pixels, losing spatial information and making the gradient calculation worthless.

`np.gradient` does handle `np.ma.masked_array`s, but the performance is an order of magnitude worse:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit_context import timeit_context

phi = np.random.randint(low=-100, high=100, size=[100, 100])
phi_mask = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=phi.shape, dtype=np.bool)

with timeit_context('full array'):
    for i2 in range(1000):
        phi_masked_grad1 = np.gradient(phi)

with timeit_context('masked_array'):
    phi_masked = np.ma.masked_array(phi, ~phi_mask)
    for i1 in range(1000):
        phi_masked_grad2 = np.gradient(phi_masked)
```

This produces the output below:

```
[full array] finished in 143 ms
[masked_array] finished in 1961 ms
```

I think its because operations run on `masked_array`s are not vectorized, but I'm not sure.

Is there any way of restricting `np.gradient` so as to achieve better performance?

This `timeit_context` is a handy timer that works like this, if anyone is interested:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import time

@contextmanager
def timeit_context(name):
    """
    Use it to time a specific code snippet
    Usage: 'with timeit_context('Testcase1'):'
    :param name: Name of the context
    """
    start_time = time.time()
    yield
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print('[{}] finished in {} ms'.format(name, int(elapsed_time * 1000)))
```

Comment: Do your areas of interest really look the way `phi_mask` suggests, i.e. a scattered subset of pixels of your array? Or are there in fact several isolated larger patches that are of interest? If the former is the case, I doubt that computing the gradient will give a meaningful result regardless of performance. Otherwise, please adjust your example to be more representative of the actual situation.

Comment: The latter is the case. `phi_mask` masks long, about 5-pixel thick strands that cut the dataset

Comment: Okay. I quickly played around a bit, looking into a solution that uses `scipy.ndimage.label`, followed by computing the gradient for the bounding box of each labeled area. However, while this is a bit faster than `masked_arrays` for a small example, it doesn't scale well enough to beat straight-up running the whole array. I also had a quick look at `scipy.sparse` arrays, but I couldn't find a `gradient` method applicable for them.

Comment: Well, that's me done - nothing useful coming to mind at this point. Someone smarter than me will have to take a look at this. +1 for the question and for `timeit_context`.

Comment: How dense is your masked array (What is the percentage of True Pixels in your mask) ? Do you need gradients at the border pixels? If yes which method do you prefer? The numpy gradients method is really slow. Simpy calculating the gradients by hand is about 3 times faster.

Comment: Something like 90%+ will be masked (True on the mask). I don't care about the borders at all. Later I'll post how I'm currently handling this, which involves keeping a straight up list of ravel()'d indices of the 2D array that I care about. It's surprisingly a lot faster than passing the entire array around, which is not something I'd expect for numpy/matlab I guess

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but this is what I've managed to patch together for my situation, which works pretty well:

I get 1D indices of the pixels where the condition is true (in this case the condition being `< 5` for example):

```
def get_indices_1d(image, band_thickness):
    return np.where(image.reshape(-1) < 5)[0]
```

This gives me a 1D array with those indices.

Then I manually calculate the gradient at those positions, in different ways:

```
def gradient_at_points1(image, indices_1d):
    width = image.shape[1]
    size = image.size

    # Using this instead of ravel() is more likely to produce a view instead of a copy
    raveled_image = image.reshape(-1)

    res_x = 0.5 * (raveled_image[(indices_1d + 1) % size] - raveled_image[(indices_1d - 1) % size])
    res_y = 0.5 * (raveled_image[(indices_1d + width) % size] - raveled_image[(indices_1d - width) % size])

    return [res_y, res_x]


def gradient_at_points2(image, indices_1d):
    indices_2d = np.unravel_index(indices_1d, dims=image.shape)

    # Even without doing the actual deltas this is already slower, and we'll have to check boundary conditions, etc
    res_x = 0.5 * (image[indices_2d] - image[indices_2d])
    res_y = 0.5 * (image[indices_2d] - image[indices_2d])

    return [res_y, res_x]


def gradient_at_points3(image, indices_1d):
    width = image.shape[1]

    raveled_image = image.reshape(-1)

    res_x = 0.5 * (raveled_image.take(indices_1d + 1, mode='wrap') - raveled_image.take(indices_1d - 1, mode='wrap'))
    res_y = 0.5 * (raveled_image.take(indices_1d + width, mode='wrap') - raveled_image.take(indices_1d - width, mode='wrap'))

    return [res_y, res_x]


def gradient_at_points4(image, indices_1d):
    width = image.shape[1]

    raveled_image = image.ravel()

    res_x = 0.5 * (raveled_image.take(indices_1d + 1, mode='wrap') - raveled_image.take(indices_1d - 1, mode='wrap'))
    res_y = 0.5 * (raveled_image.take(indices_1d + width, mode='wrap') - raveled_image.take(indices_1d - width, mode='wrap'))

    return [res_y, res_x]
```

My test arrays look like this:

```
a = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=[512, 512])

# Force edges to not pass the condition
a[:, 0] = 99
a[:, -1] = 99
a[0, :] = 99
a[-1, :] = 99

indices = get_indices_1d(a, 5)

mask = a < 5
```

Then I can run these tests:

```
with timeit_context('full gradient'):
    for i in range(100):
        grad1 = np.gradient(a)

with timeit_context('With masked_array'):
    for im in range(100):
        ma = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask)
        grad6 = np.gradient(ma)

with timeit_context('gradient at points 1'):
    for i1 in range(100):
        grad2 = gradient_at_points1(image=a, indices_1d=indices)

with timeit_context('gradient at points 2'):
    for i2 in range(100):
        grad3 = gradient_at_points2(image=a, indices_1d=indices)

with timeit_context('gradient at points 3'):
    for i3 in range(100):
        grad4 = gradient_at_points3(image=a, indices_1d=indices)

with timeit_context('gradient at points 4'):
    for i4 in range(100):
        grad5 = gradient_at_points4(image=a, indices_1d=indices)
```

Which give the following results:

```
[full gradient] finished in 576 ms
[With masked_array] finished in 3455 ms
[gradient at points 1] finished in 421 ms
[gradient at points 2] finished in 451 ms
[gradient at points 3] finished in 112 ms
[gradient at points 4] finished in 102 ms
```

As you can see method 4 is by far the best (don't care much about how much memory its consuming however).

This probably only holds because my 2D array is relatively small (512x512). Maybe with much larger arrays this won't be true.

Another caveat is that `ndarray.take(indices, mode='wrap')` will do some weird stuff around the image edges (one row will 'loop' into the next, etc) to maintain good performance, so if edges are ever important for your application you might want to pad the input array with 1 pixel around the edges.

Still super interesting how slow `masked_array`s are. Pulling the constructor `ma = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask)` outside the loop doesn't affect the time since the `masked_array` itself just keeps references to the array and its mask